# Spring Cloud StreamListener @Output KStream Serdes dont seem to work

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have a Stream Listener as

```
@StreamListener(target = "requesti")
@SendTo("responseo")
public KStream<UUID,Account> process(KStream<UUID, Account> events) {
    // Predicate<UUID, Event> isAccount = (key, value) ->
    // value.getEntity().getClass().equals(Account.class);

    // @formatter:off
    return events
            //.filter(isAccount)
            .peek((key, value) -> {
                log.debug("Processing {} {}", key, value);
            });
            /*
            .filter(isAccount)
            .map((key, value) -> process(value))

            .peek((key, value) -> {
                log.debug("Processed {} {}", key, value);
            });
            */
    // @formatter:on

}
```

Where the @Input("requesti") config is as follows;

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.requesti.consumer.application-id=repo-event-consumer
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.requesti.destination=request
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.requesti.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.requesti.consumer.header-mode=raw
```

and the @output("responseo") config is as follows

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.responseo.consumer.application-id=repo-response-producer
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.responseo.destination=response
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.responseo.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.responseo.producer.header-mode=raw
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.responseo.producer.use-native-encoding=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.responseo.producer.key-serde=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.responseo.producer.value-serde=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde
```

My Processor recieves a request and can send output as well, but the out put is as follows

[Producer clientId=**repo-event-consumer**-49827b40-2357-4af0-8103-228343faa59e-StreamThread-1-producer] Sending record ProducerRecord(topic=response, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = **TypeId**, value = [117, 107, 46, 111, 114, 103, 46, 99, 97, 116, 97, 112, 117, 108, 116, 46, 101, 115, 46, 99, 117, 98, 101, 46, 115, 101, 114, 118, 105, 99, 101, 115, 46, 97, 99, 99, 111, 117, 110, 116, 46, 109, 111, 100, 101, 108, 46, 65, 99, 99, 111, 117, 110, 116])], isReadOnly = true), key=[B@6a5e4294, value=[B@5a0852e1, timestamp=1551093349173) with callback org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl$1@336dbba5 to topic response partition 2

Few Things i am confused with Producer Record id is not "repo-response-producer" and secondly key-serde/value-serde is not used, in my mind it should have been

Sending record ProducerRecord(topic=request, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = **Key_TypeId**, value = [106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 117, 116, 105, 108, 46, 85, 85, 73, 68]), RecordHeader(key = **TypeId**, value = [117, 107, 46, 111, 114, 103, 46, 99, 97, 116, 97, 112, 117, 108, 116, 46, 101, 115, 46, 99, 117, 98, 101, 46, 115, 101, 114, 118, 105, 99, 101, 115, 46, 97, 99, 99, 111, 117, 110, 116, 46, 109, 111, 100, 101, 108, 46, 65, 99, 99, 111, 117, 110, 116])], isReadOnly = true), key=6f0f50e2-3add-4d22-a370-cac66d016af0, value=Account() with callback org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate$$Lambda$582/533392019@85ab964 to topic request partition 2

and the default serdeConfig is

```
    spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde
```

[Repo](https://github.com/zafarale/catapult/invitations)

Comment: Hi, you don't need to set the application-id on the output. The one that you set on the input is applicable to the entire processor (both input and output). As to your second `Serde` issue, I am not sure whats going on by looking at the output. Do you see a message `Native encoding is enabled for responseo...` on the console? Can you give us a small sample in which we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: spring.cloud.stream.bindings.reponseo.use-native-encoding=true is enabled, i am scratching my head now how to add type info @OutPut and its KStream to allow ResponseHandler KStream to be able to identify various Json Payload to Java Types.

Comment: any chance you can provide a small reproducible standalone app?

Comment: Is there a way i can associate partitions to processor lets say based on hashCode of  type name which will collate all similar messages in one partition and if i can instruct Kstream to only read from that partition and response on same partition number of response topic.

Comment: will you be available on some chat, i am desperate

Comment: what I suggest is to create a small sample app where we can run to see the issues, then can make recommendations.

Comment: Did you check out these samples? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples

Comment: Please check link in edited post

Comment: I did a while ago

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are trying to solve 2 issues, 1. the json serde on the output side is not working. 2. the partitioning issue you mentioned in the comments. I will see if I can provide a sample application where the serdes are working.

Comment: Correct I will be grateful to you for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample that demonstrates the working of `JsonSerde` on the outbound using the Kafka Streams binder: https://github.com/schacko-samples/json-serde-example.
Run the sample and make sure it works.
Take a look at the `application.yml` for the configuration details. I put some details in the provided `README`.

Comment: Can I transform stream uuid, model into ktable not reduce or group

Comment: I will try it in morning

Comment: It should be possible. Please use that sample I provided to see if it works. That way, its easy on our end to debug.

Comment: I tried   bindings:
    requesti.destination: data-in
    responseo:
      destination: data-out
      producer:
        use-native-encoding: true
        partition-count: 10
        partition-key-extractor-name: customExtractor

Comment: My assumption is using custom keyExtractor respone will be sent to a unique partition, Likewise i want stream processor to only read from one partition on request topic

Comment: I got sample end to end working, with KStreams, as i have few servcies sharing Topic and intending to use partition as their read/write segments on both request/response topics i like to associate stream mapping with partition for both input and output

Comment: @ZafarAli Glad to hear it worked for you. Are you good with all the issues then?

Comment: Not all, if its not too much os ask, can i configure/force streams consumer/processor to only read/write on particular partition, i tried following cause out many services only one partition should be used be repository
# Doesnt work
#spring.cloud.stream.bindings.api-request-in.producer.partition-key-extractor-name=streamPartitionKeyExtractor
#
#spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.processor-response-out.producer.configuration.partitioner.class

Comment: and how do i convert Kstream UUID, Model to Ktable model without reducing/count

Comment: Is there a dictionary of all these properties and its usage as i find available documentation very frustrating (it may just be me).

Comment: I think this issue is going way out of scope. Can you start a new SO question so that we can narrow the scope? Lets keep this one to the issues you had with the `JsonSerde`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888311/spring-cloud-stream-topic-partitions-kstream-read-write

Comment: @sobychako did you had a chance to look onto the new question link i posted earlier

Comment: I just answered there.

Comment: @sobychacko how to provide JSON type at the individual binding level rather than default binding.

Comment: @Kumar225 which version of Spring Cloud Stream you are using? If you can upgrade to 3.0 (not yet GA'ed), the binder will infer the Serde for the bindings.